# Executing Yield return stops the Coroutine in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

When I'm using `yield return null;` or any other return type, I get my coroutine end. I have `for` loop to print all the letters with interval, but when I execute `yield return` IEnumerator coroutine ends

But without `yield` it works fine.

Here is the code

````
    public Text text;
    Animation anim;
    public Coroutine cor = null;
    private bool corR = false;
    public float timing = 0.0f;

    public void ChangeText(string txt)
    {
        if (cor != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(cor);
            cor = null;
        }

        cor = StartCoroutine(__change(timing, txt));
    }

    IEnumerator __change(float time, string txt)
    {
        text.text = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < txt.Length; i++)
        {
            text.text += txt[i];

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
        }


        corR = false;
    }```
````

Comment: How are you starting your coroutine?

Comment: Here is the function to start coroutine.

public void ChangeText(string txt)
    {
        if (cor != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(cor);
            cor = null;
        }

        cor = StartCoroutine(__change(timing, txt));
    }

Comment: ... and when you say that the coroutine "ends" -- do you mean that it returns? If so, that's expected. Do you mean that the next iteration of the `for` loop is never executed, even after waiting for `time` seconds?

Comment: yes, after yield return loop never executed again, that's the problem.

Comment: Have you tried setting `timing` to a value above `0.0`?

Comment: @SasisaPlay your code works fine for me, check the value of ´time´ in the Unity Editor

Comment: Yes, i tried timing above 0. That's the problem, it must work, there is no mistake. But it doesn't...

Comment: How are you calling changetext? Are you calling it from the inspector? If so, make sure you have the `dynamic` one selected. If you call the regular one, without specifying a string manually, your string will always be empty and therefore the coroutine ends immediatly (txt.length is 0 then)

Comment: I call it from another script just by text.textChange("Lorem Ipsum Dolar Sit Amet"); After that i get "L" as the text and the loop stops. In the console i see only one time loop execution if i print Debug.Log()

Answer (score 2):

The code per se looks fine and if nothing else interferes with this script (like e.g. disabling it etc.) to me it sounds like your [`Time.timescale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html) is `0`

[`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) depends on the [`Time.timescale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html).

> The real time suspended is equal to the given time **divided by [`Time.timescale`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html)**. See [`WaitForSecondsRealtime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSecondsRealtime.html) if you wish to wait using **unscaled** time. [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) can only be used with a yield statement in coroutines.

So if this is the case you rather want to use [`WaitForSecondsRealtime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSecondsRealtime.html)

```
IEnumerator __change(float time, string txt)
{
    // you might probably also want to set this in the beginning
    corR = true;

    text.text = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < txt.Length; i++)
    {
        text.text += txt[i];

        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(time);
    }

    corR = false;
}
```